# Broken pipe appears when request http service through unix domain socket

Tags: linux, sockets, go

```sh
# go version
go version go1.13.9 linux/amd64
```

```sh
# uname -a
Linux iZ8vbaym9jmge8qd5hlcpiZ 4.15.0-111-generic #112-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 20:32:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

http server as follow:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
  _ "net/http/pprof"
)

func main() {

    h2 := func(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("555555")
        if _, err := w.Write(make([]byte, 9999)); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("---=====: ", err.Error(), syscall.EPIPE == err)
            return
        }
    }
  go func() {
      log.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":6060", nil))
  }()
    http.HandleFunc("/endpoint", h2)
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGPIPE)
    go func() {
        sig := <-sigs
    fmt.Println("6666666666", sig.String())
        fmt.Println(sig)
    }()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8888", nil))
}
```

1、 by unix domain socket

curl request  `curl 127.0.0.1:8888/endpoint -m 0.2`
result:

```sh
555555
---=====:  write tcp 127.0.0.1:8888->127.0.0.1:33794: write: broken pipe false
6666666666 broken pipe
broken pipe
```

2、 by tcp socket

curl request:  `curl 47.92.3.20:8888/endpoint -m 0.2`
get result: `555555`

Does go's netpoll handle unix domain socket and tcp socket in different ways? I don’t see the difference in netpoll code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find any difference in the connection handling, because both situations are handled the same way. This is not particular to Go at all, in a unix socket the writing side of the connection can detect immediately when the connection is closed.

In a TCP socket, there is no way to immediately detect a closed connection. You can wait for a recv call to return 0 (or `io.EOF` in go), which is what happens in some cases and is how `Request.Context` is canceled, but it cannot immediately cover the case of a dropped connection. When the remote host leaves while data is being sent, all you can do is continue writing until the TCP stack receives an RST or ICMP message indicating that the connection is no longer usable. Once this happens, on most unix-like systems you will get the same `broken pipe` error from the system.

Comment: Does unix socket have no buffer because it is IPC?

Comment: @helios, sorry, that was confusing so I removed it.  there is a buffer but it is effectively smaller and more responsive because there are only local processes involved. The term “IPC” isn’t relevant here, there’s lots of things you can use for IPC

Comment: Thank you for your answers, now there are two questions:
1、 Through the TCP socket request, why the RST packet is received but there is no broken pipe?
2、 Why is there no broken pipe error if I reduce the size of the response(9999 -> 1500) in the above go code?